# Removing trailing newline in custom environment

Tags: line-breaking

I am relying on the output of a 3rd party tool which I cannot really
modify at the moment. It generates a soup of commands corresponding
to a semantically annotated translation of some source code.
By playing with the definition of various commands I can get it
rendered as semantically highlighted source code.

My issue is that every line of source code is terminated with a call to
a newline command which means that I always end up with a trailing newline
in the code environment.

Here is a MWE showing the problem and the desired output:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{code}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=yellow!5, linewidth=0pt]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
}

\newcommand{\CodeKeyword}[1]{\texttt{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CodeSpace}{\texttt{\hphantom{ }}}
\newcommand{\CodeIdentifier}[1]{\texttt{\color{purple}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CodeData}[1]{\texttt{\color{red}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CodeNewline}{\\}

\begin{document}

Current output:

\begin{code}
\CodeKeyword{let}\CodeSpace{}\CodeIdentifier{x}\CodeSpace{}\CodeNewline
\CodeSpace{}\CodeSpace{}\CodeKeyword{=}\CodeSpace{}\CodeData{1}\CodeNewline
\end{code}

I wish it were equivalent to:

%% Same code except for the last \CodeNewline
\begin{code}
\CodeKeyword{let}\CodeSpace{}\CodeIdentifier{x}\CodeSpace{}\CodeNewline
\CodeSpace{}\CodeSpace{}\CodeKeyword{=}\CodeSpace{}\CodeData{1}%\CodeNewline
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

[image: Current output vs expected output]

Edit: my current hack of a solution is to have my `Makefile` use `perl` to postprocess the generated files like so:

```bash
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\\CodeNewline{}\n\\end{code}/\n\\end{code}/igs'
```

(Credits: this SO answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26289/159035)

Answer (score 3):

Redefine `\CodeNewline` to be `\par` and remove the standard indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{code}{%
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=yellow!5, linewidth=0pt]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
}

\newcommand{\CodeKeyword}[1]{\texttt{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CodeSpace}{\texttt{\hphantom{ }}}
\newcommand{\CodeIdentifier}[1]{\texttt{\color{purple}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CodeData}[1]{\texttt{\color{red}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CodeNewline}{\par}

\begin{document}

Current output:

\begin{code}
\CodeKeyword{let}\CodeSpace{}\CodeIdentifier{x}\CodeSpace{}\CodeNewline
\CodeSpace{}\CodeSpace{}\CodeKeyword{=}\CodeSpace{}\CodeData{1}\CodeNewline
\end{code}

I wish it were equivalent to:

%% Same code except for the last \CodeNewline
\begin{code}
\CodeKeyword{let}\CodeSpace{}\CodeIdentifier{x}\CodeSpace{}\CodeNewline
\CodeSpace{}\CodeSpace{}\CodeKeyword{=}\CodeSpace{}\CodeData{1}%\CodeNewline
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine `\CodeNewline` to look at the next token; if it is equal to `\end` then do nothing. Otherwise insert a line break.

```
\newcommand{\CodeNewline}[1]{\ifx#1\end\relax\else\\\fi#1}
```

However, doing this will only remove the ultimate newline at the end of an environment. If you ended the environment with multiple newlines, I would assume you would want to strip all of them too. So we can further edit the definition to keep track of how many newlines we've seen.

While we are at it, we can also make multiple consecutive `\CodeNewline`s insert more or less space than a full blank line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% One can use two consecutive \CodeNewline to get a blank line, 
% but maybe we don't want a full blank line and just want some extra space
% this length defines how tall the blank line(s) ought to be. 
\newlength\codeextrabaselineskip
\setlength\codeextrabaselineskip{0.6\baselineskip}
\newcounter{gallaisNLcount}

\newenvironment{code}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=yellow!5, linewidth=1pt]% changed linewidth so you can see effect
    \setcounter{gallaisNLcount}{0}
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
}

\newcommand{\CodeKeyword}[1]{\texttt{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CodeSpace}{\texttt{\hphantom{ }}}
\newcommand{\CodeIdentifier}[1]{\texttt{\color{purple}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CodeData}[1]{\texttt{\color{red}{#1}}}
% Tests for the next token. If it is equal to \end we do nothing.
% If it is equal to another \CodeNewline we increment the count of currently seen newlines.
% For anything else, it prints a linebreak with extra space proportional to the number of newlines seen, and resets the counter. 
% Whatever we do, put the next token back where it ought to be, since we are just peeking, not processing. 
\newcommand{\CodeNewline}[1]{\ifx#1\end\relax\else\ifx#1\CodeNewline\stepcounter{gallaisNLcount}\else\\[\thegallaisNLcount\codeextrabaselineskip]\setcounter{gallaisNLcount}{0}\fi\fi#1}


\begin{document}

Current output:

\begin{code}
\CodeKeyword{let}\CodeSpace{}\CodeIdentifier{x}\CodeSpace{}\CodeNewline
\CodeSpace{}\CodeSpace{}\CodeKeyword{=}\CodeSpace{}\CodeData{1}\CodeNewline\CodeNewline\CodeNewline
\CodeKeyword{let}\CodeSpace{}\CodeIdentifier{x}\CodeSpace{}\CodeNewline
\CodeSpace{}\CodeSpace{}\CodeKeyword{=}\CodeSpace{}\CodeData{1}\CodeNewline\CodeNewline
\CodeKeyword{let}\CodeSpace{}\CodeIdentifier{x}\CodeSpace{}\CodeNewline
\CodeSpace{}\CodeSpace{}\CodeKeyword{=}\CodeSpace{}\CodeData{1}\CodeNewline\CodeNewline
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

[image]